# What Does The White Number In The Blue Hexagon Mean?

Tags: android, puzzle-and-dragons

Today, when I logged onto Puzzles And Dragons, I noticed a blue hexagon with a white 15 under my name when I signed into Google Play. What does that number mean and what is it for?
I would show a picture, but the one I took is really blurry and you can't see the number.

**EDIT:** Here's a picture I found on the Internet.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the level you have in the [Google Play Games](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.play.games) app. In the picture below you see exactly what you mean, and it is part of one of the sceenshots on Google Play itself.

[image: Blue hexagon with level]

So it doesn't have to do anything with this game in particular, as a lot of different games yield experience and therefor level you up. Every time you sign into Google Play, the pop-up you showed will be displayed.